# DDD Entity factory responsibility

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

***Creating instances***

I am new to DDD and wondering if the **Factory** that creates the **Entity** is responsible for creating the **Value Objects**. Here is a small example of what I have until this moment:

```
class User extends Entity {
    public name: UserName;

    constructor (name: UserName) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class UserName extends ValueObject {
    public userName: string;
}

class UserFactory {
    public create(string name) {
        return new User(
            new UserName(name)
        );
    }
}
```

I think that way the components that create an user (UserEntity) just need to pass the **string** to the factory and thats all. But on the other side this code is not following the **Single responsibility principle**. Maybe it is better to just pass the **UserName** value object directly?

```
class UserFactory {
    public create(UserName userName) {
        return new User(
            userName
        );
    }
}
```

***Validation***

The other concept that is still unclear to me is the validation. Talking about the validation when creating the object (**UserEntity)**. Is the **UserFactory** responsible for it? For example:

```
class UserFactory {
    public create(UserName userName, UserLastName userLastName) {
        if (userName == userLastName)
            // throw validation exception

        return new User(
            userName,
            userLastName
        );
    }
}
```

Image I added **lastName** to the **UserEntity** as **ValueObject**. I know it is dummy to compare the both names but just to give an example.
So is it correct that way - to remove the responsibility from the **UserEntity** or the following snippet is better:

```
class User extends Entity {
    public name: UserName;
    public lastName: UserLastName;

    constructor (name: UserName, lastName: UserLastName) {
        if (name == lastName)
            // throw validation exception

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

The most interesting thing to me is when there is a change in the constructor of the **Entity** (add more required parameters to the constructor). I am searching for the approach that is going to cause the smallest number of changes as possible - using **Factory pattern** of just the constructor of the **Entity**? What are the biggest advantages in using **Factory** over the simple way - constructor (if there are).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be complicating things. The factory pattern is not really part of DDD, but it's a design pattern to use when building an object is complex or you want to hide some of the attributes that the Entity needs to work (for example in UIs, the elements might need some access to the class that does the rendering). There's a lot more info if you go to duckduckgo and search for `design factory pattern`

The examples you showed don't really require a factory. If all the factory is doing is passing parameters to a constructor, it's not adding anything.

About validation, the idea is that a constructor should never return successfully if an object is not usable, so in your examples, the null validations should be in the constructor of the object if the parameter cannot be null.

About value objects, again, why do you need a Factory? What benefit does it bring? I honestly cannot think of one case where it makes sense to have a Factory class. Sometimes, to make code a bit cleaner, one might use a factory method. For example, in Java the class Optional can only be constructed by calling the static builder method `Optional.of()` (which by the way, does some extra validation that only applies to that method).

TL;DR: use a Factory class if it brings a benefit, otherwise just instantiate class directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I undesrstand, in the examples I gave to use factory pattern is useless. But can you give me some examples of when it is good to use it.

Comment: Look at the [Flyweight Patter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). This pattern caches previously created objects. The **responsibility** of the factory is to keep the maintain the cache and return previously created objects. There are probably a few hundred other use cases to use this pattern.